# Debugger tool for VS, that let me watch the object, not the reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I m looking for an add-on/tool of visual studio that let me do advanced debugging.
specifically, i want to watch an object, what ever the reference is, and get a break when a property change for example.

now VS let me watch the reference, and make condition on breakpoints

in other words, something where i can specifies a reference , and the tool watch the object not only the ref.

thanks

Comment: but the reference does point to the object? What exactly can not be done with the features existing in VS?

Comment: the object is what contain the data. the reference what point on it. for an object their must be a lot of references modifying it...

Comment: I think, what he wants is to break the program, as soon as the property of a certain object instance changes. Something similar to breaking in VC++ when a certain memory part changes.

Comment: Can't you just make a static variable and assign the object to that?  Then you can watch the static variable.

Comment: This doesn't help him. BTW, you could achieve this easier with the feature "Make Object ID".

Comment: @Hassan 'for an object their must be a lot of references modifying it' - you mean a lot of references exist, pointing to the one object? So simply pick one and investigate the properties in a conditional breakpoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [Make Object ID](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/04/make-objectid-vstipdebug0015.aspx)

As for your 2nd request, of breaking whenever a property changes, that's what's called a Data Breakpoint in C++, and is not supported in managed code. The best you can do is put a breakpoint in the property setter (or, if it is a field or an auto property, turn it into a regular property with backing field, recompile, and then put a breakpoint on the setter.

If you want to break only when the specific object changes, you can put a Condition on your breakpoint, such as "this == 1#", where 1# is the ObjectID of the object you are trying to track for changes, and then it will break only when the property of that specific object is changed.

Comment: Slight fix to the above. It should be `this == 1#`. The # should be after the Object ID.

Comment: Thank you. Updated accordingly.